# Sql Server select case dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, case

I am trying to create a stored procedure that takes two dates (reportStartDate, reportEndDate).

The idea is to return everything ("startDate", "endDate" and "term" are the important columns) including the amount of working days between "reportStartDate" and "reportEndDate" but the "startDate" and "endDate"  could fall inbetween the "reportStartDate" and "reportEndDate" so i need to check if this happens and use those dates to work out the days.
(if "term" = 1 then use "endDate" else use "reportEndDate")

I use this code to get the working days

`(DATEDIFF(dd,startDate,endDate) - (2* DATEDIFF(wk,startDate,endDate)))+1 AS BusinessDayCount`

And this for the stored procedure which obviously doesn't work

```
Create  PROCEDURE testPro(    
@reportStartDate date,
@reportEndDate date    
)    
AS
BEGIN    
SELECT emp, surname, startDate, endDate, 
CASE WHEN startDate<= @reportStartDate 
THEN (DATEDIFF(dd,@reportStartDate, @reportEndDate) - (2* DATEDIFF(wk,@reportStartDate,@reportEndDate)))+1 AS BusinessDayCount 
ELSE (DATEDIFF(dd,startDate, @reportEndDate) - (2* DATEDIFF(wk,startDate,@reportEndDate)))+1 AS BusinessDayCount END 
FROM Table_1
END
EXEC  testPro '2012-01-01', '2012-12-31'
```

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: `which obviously doesn't work` why? clarify more about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any issue with your procedure except the case statement. which should be as below

```
CASE WHEN startDate<= @reportStartDate 
THEN (DATEDIFF(dd,@reportStartDate, @reportEndDate) - (2* 
DATEDIFF(wk,@reportStartDate,@reportEndDate)))+1  
ELSE (DATEDIFF(dd,startDate, @reportEndDate) - (2* 
DATEDIFF(wk,startDate,@reportEndDate)))+1 END AS BusinessDayCount
```

Syntax is:

```
case when (condition) then some_value 
else some_other_value end as some_alias_name
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will work fine in SQL Server:

`CREATE PROCEDURE testPro @reportStartDate date, @reportEndDate date

AS

SELECT emp, surname, startDate, endDate, 
(DATEDIFF(dd, @reportStartDate, @reportEndDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @reportStartDate, @reportEndDate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @reportStartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @reportEndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BusinessDayCount
FROM Table_1
GO`

I've replaced your calculation for the BusinessDayCount with another calculation which is slightly more accurate (assuming your business days run from Monday - Friday), if not then you can simply replace that bit of code with the following:

```
CASE WHEN startDate<= @reportStartDate 
THEN (DATEDIFF(dd,@reportStartDate, @reportEndDate) - (2* 
DATEDIFF(wk,@reportStartDate,@reportEndDate)))+1  
ELSE (DATEDIFF(dd,startDate, @reportEndDate) - (2* 
DATEDIFF(wk,startDate,@reportEndDate)))+1 END AS BusinessDayCount
```